# How do I unwrap the phase from a Fourier transform in a way that makes physical sense?

Tags: python, scipy, fft, physics, scikit-image

To extract data from an 2D image, I have:

- Fourier transformed the image using `scipy.fft.fft2()`
- cropped out a specific peak that I want to investigate
- performed the inverse Fourier transform with `scipy.fft.ifft2()`

I am interested in the phase of this inverse Fourier transform and not its amplitude. I am investigating a row of pixels in the image has a large phase shift.

The initial data look like this

[image: The initial data look like this.]

This is what the data look like after unwrapping with np.unwrap:

[image: This is what the data look like after unwrapping with np.unwrap.]

This is the image I have taken the row of pixels from:
[image: This is the image I have taken the row of pixels from.] There is an object in the center which changes the phase of the light that passes through it.

I am expecting a peak/trough in the phase (like a bell curve).

I do not know why one part of the data has a sharp jump of +2π on only one side and why there is not a corresponding jump back down of -2π. After unwrapping, I end up with two sides 2π apart when they should have the same value.

I have tried using both `numpy.unwrap()` and `scikit.restoration.unwrap_phase()`.

Comment: The jump from `-pi` to `+pi` in your initial data is because the FFT's output phase range is _defined_ as `[-pi, +pi]`. Hence when the phase passes the -pi boundary, the system adds `2pi` to it, yielding a phase just under `+pi`.   For the`unwrap()` call, imagine watching a satellite in orbit. The satellite passed your arbirtrary "midnight" position. You can either deal with a discontinuity in the data or notice that it's more than one orbit away from where you wanted to start.

Comment: There is no peak in the initial data, or at least not clearly seen. The single discontinuity is at ~220 a.u., so the unwrapped curve looks correct. Please note that your curve looks like an integral of bell-curve.

Comment: If I understand your procedure correctly, you've cropped in _frequency_ space and are trying to reconstruct an image which uses only the retained frequencies.  Is that correct? If so, you should make sure your input to `ifft2()` retains all the original frequency components, but with the amplitudes of the uninteresting frequencies set to 0.  (If you're changing the size of the matrix and the offset of the interesting data when you "crop", you're changing the data.) Also note you probably want both the positive- and negative-frequency components to avoid getting complex outputs.

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/37931-how-to-remove-frequency-components-in-an-image

Comment: @SarahMesser Yes, you're correct. I have an interference pattern formed at the camera which I take the Fourier transform of. I'm taking a window around one peak and applying a Gaussian window to taper it to zero at the edge. I want the complex inputs as the data I am analysing is looking at the phase shift of light travelling through an object. 

I don't think my code for the Fourier transform is faulty. It has worked well for other data so I am unsure why it doesn't work here. If you look at the picture I have added in the edit, you can see there's a  cigar shaped object in the middle.

Comment: It's not clear to me why programming knowledge is necessary to approach the question, as opposed to it simply being a *math* question.

Comment: math.stackexchange has a section on image processing, and several of the questions there deal with Fourier transforms: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bimage-processing%5D+fourier+transform

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is it possible to crosspost to math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: It will be better if you rewrite the question there to explain it in an abstract mathematical context.

Comment: @zaphod It's also possible this is a _physics_ question, depending on how your initial phases / image is generated: If the gradient in the phase is too high, it might be lost... in which case you're faced with choosing between higher-resolution imagery and fitting a model to the imaged phase and fitting the phase jumps.  Look around https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: This might also be suited for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ —— It seems to me that you conflate a change in phase of the light with a change in phase of spatial frequencies in the image. Maybe your experimental setup translates the one into the other, but typically these are not related. You should also know that cropping the frequency domain means you change the meaning of each frequency component, you should probably not do this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I compensate for the cropping by changing the pixel length of the inverse transform in my program. As I am cropping out zeroes, I would have thought that there was no information lost otherwise.

Comment: Each bin of the frequency domain is associated to a specific frequency, there is a relation between the position and the frequency. Cropping means each bin becomes a different frequency. There is no way to compensate for that.